# Taxonomy and Rewrite Structure

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type (recipes) and custom taxonomy (r_cat).  To be quite honest, I'm a newbie and I've tried different scenarios and options from what I've read in various posts and google searches, but, I can't get it to do what I need.

Here is the code:

```
add_action('init', 'cptui_register_my_cpt_recipes');
function cptui_register_my_cpt_recipes() {
register_post_type('recipes', array(
'label' => 'Healthy Recipes',
'description' => '',
'public' => true,
'show_ui' => true,
'show_in_menu' => true,
'capability_type' => 'post',
'map_meta_cap' => true,
'hierarchical' => false,
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'healthy-recipes', 'with_front' => true),
'query_var' => true,
'has_archive' => true,
'supports' => array('title','editor','custom-fields','thumbnail','page-attributes','post-formats'),
'taxonomies' => array('post_tag','r_cat'),
'labels' => array (
  'name' => 'Healthy Recipes',
  'singular_name' => 'Recipe',
  'menu_name' => 'Recipes',
  'add_new' => 'Add Recipe',
  'add_new_item' => 'Add New Recipe',
  'edit' => 'Edit',
  'edit_item' => 'Edit Recipe',
  'new_item' => 'New Recipe',
  'view' => 'View Recipe',
  'view_item' => 'View Recipe',
  'search_items' => 'Search Recipes',
  'not_found' => 'No Recipes Found',
  'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Recipes Found in Trash',
  'parent' => 'Parent Recipe',
)
) ); }

add_action('init', 'cptui_register_my_taxes_r_cat');
function cptui_register_my_taxes_r_cat() {
register_taxonomy( 'r_cat',array (
  0 => 'recipes',
),
array( 'hierarchical' => true,
'label' => 'Recipe Categories',
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'healthy-recipes' ),
    'show_admin_column' => false,
    'labels' => array (
  'search_items' => 'Recipe Category',
  'popular_items' => '',
  'all_items' => '',
  'parent_item' => '',
  'parent_item_colon' => '',
  'edit_item' => '',
  'update_item' => '',
  'add_new_item' => '',
  'new_item_name' => '',
  'separate_items_with_commas' => '',
  'add_or_remove_items' => '',
  'choose_from_most_used' => '',
)
) ); 
}
```

When I just set the taxonomy to:
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'healthy-recipes' ),
The result is a 404 page.

When I just set it to:
    'rewrite' => true,
The result is a URL like this:  http://website.com/r_cat/gluten-free-recipes/

What I really need is a URL like:  http://website.com/gluten-free-recipes/

What do I need to change, or maybe add...to achieve this structure?

What else do you need to know?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this and re-save your Permalinks after modifying the permalink structure http://vip.wordpress.com/documentation/remove-the-slug-from-your-custom-post-type-permalinks/

Comment: I tested, changing the "event" to recipes and it had absolutely no effect.